# Remove dim from UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, swift3, background, uipopovercontroller, uipopoverbackgroundview

I've set its `popoverBackgroundViewClass` to a custom `UIPopoverBackgroundView`, and there I do:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    // more stuff here 
}
```

But the popover keeps showing a very light black or grey dim behind.

I've seen posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925699/remove-dimming-view-behind-uipopoverpresentationcontroller) with similar issue and no solution found. That post is related to `UIPopoverController` that is deprecated, I'm using `UIPopoverPresentationController`, is it really possible to do this? Has somebody found a way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off dimming by UIPopoverController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550550/turning-off-dimming-by-uipopovercontroller)

Comment: @KKRocks that is regarding the old `UIPopoverController`

Comment: what is the difference in old UIPopoverController

Comment: @KKRocks `UIPopoverController` is deprecated, now we have `UIPopoverPresentationController`, different API and maybe different behavior and options for being customized, I don't know.